# Gelatin before or after dry hopping

Tags: secondary, ipa, gelatin

Going to dry hop on my IPA and dont know if add gelatin to primary then rack to secondary then add hops or dry hop on primary and then gelatin and then rack to secondary for aging
what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My routine is to dry hop in that primary towards the end of fermentation.  At fermentation temperatures.  Then I rack to a keg (or a secondary in your case) to add my gelatin.  But there is no "aging".  Its an IPA.  I want it to go from fermenation to dry hop to serving as quickly as I can.

Answer (score 2):

For taste and aroma, 4 to 7 days of dry hopping are optimal. For clarity I prefer to give isinglass 7 to 14 days. Probably it's the same with gelatin, these are similar. Thus, I obviously add gelatin first, hops second.

One more thing. If you want to rack to secondary, strongly consider adding gelatin after racking. I guess you will be using another bucket just for bottling? If so, racking your beer from sediment, and then adding gelatin, helps. You will not have any waste in your wort, nothing you could pick from the bottom when you stir gelatin in your beer. The less particles gelatin needs to drop to the bottom, the more effective it is. Only when you plan to bottle directly from your second fermentation bucket, adding gelatin to primary makes sense.

Comment: sometimes i add gelatin directly to primary then move to bottling bucket and bottle

Comment: My problem is last time i transfer to secondary beer get oxided and don't have co2 to purge oxygen.,

Comment: @cesarmoro This is not a discussion forum. If you want to ask about oxidation, ask it at the beginning, or [ask another question](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

I've always done finings after all fermentation addition schedules have completed.

Most finings work best during or after cold crash.

You want your hops to be warm and suspended for their dry hop duration for best results.